# ripd ospfd and bgpd all with syntax error on line 1

Tags: openbsd, quagga

I'm using an OpenBSD 5.9 VM and installed quagga recently.
I'm unable to run any dynamic routing protocol (ripd -d, ospfd -d or bgpd -d) and I get always the same error message,

example for RIP

`#ripd -d
/etc/ripd.conf:1: syntax error`

I've copied the sample file so there is no error at all.
I've also enabled ip_forwarding.

Could anybody help me please ?

Comment: My ripd file is just as simple as this 

` hostname Router

password password

enable password password 

router rip 

redistribute connected 

`

Comment: pasting your ripd.conf might be helpful, even if it is just copied from the sample; seems odd the error would be on line 1 (a comment)

Comment: Hi pete, that is exactly what is happening. I've used the sample file to start but it gives me an error on the line 1 that is a commented line !
It's really weird.
I've installed quagga with 
` pkg_add quagga` command and no error was produced.

Comment: How did you install your system? Have you manually rebuilt any parts, upgraded from a previous version, etc...? If all 3 are error-ing with _good_ configs, something must be corrupted - conf or binaries

Comment: Hi pete, I did a clean install with all the openbsd 6.0 default configs on a virtual machine on vmplayer 12. 
I've also deployed an openbsd 5.9 version with all default options and I'm getting the same error.
I've installed quagga with ` pkg_add quagga `

Please find the first 5 lines of my ripd.conf file:
` bash-4.3# ripd -d
/etc/ripd.conf:1: syntax error
bash-4.3# head -n5 /etc/ripd.conf
hostname rip
enable password zebra
#
#router rip
#  network 10.0.0.0/8
` 

Basicly this is the ripd.conf sample file. On my ubuntu server it is working perfectly.
This is really weird.

Comment: To be clear, this is the sample that came with quagga, and not the sample that came with openbsd? Its tough to read your config formatting, but none of that looks like valid a ripd.conf

Comment: oh, i think i see whats happening - Quagga supplies its own daemons, but you're using openbsd's builtin ones instead. Try running it from `/usr/local/sbin/ripd` - also it looks like pkg_add wants to install quagga configs to `/etc/quagga/ripd.conf` which might also generate an error